# "plink.exe" hangs on Windows Server 2008 R2, creates process "conhost.exe"

Tags: windows, putty, plink

I am new to the whole Windows world. I have downloaded plink.exe from Putty's website. I am executing a plink command from the Windows Server 2008 R2(64 bit) which would execute a shell script in a Linux box.

The `plink` command is executed from a `.dtsx` package which is running as a daemon job on the Windows Server. I have accepted the host key into the registry for the Linux box using Putty and I can see it in the registry.
The command executes when I RDP into the server but does not when I am not logged in. It hangs and creates a "conhost.exe" process which stays there. I can see the "plink.exe" and "conhost.exe" in the task manager on the server.

Here is the kind of command I am running.

```
plink.exe user@SERVERNAME -pw password ./script_name.sh param_1 param_2 param_3
```

Has anybody faced/or is facing any problem like this?

Comment: 1) Have you accepted the host key for the correct local account that runs the DTS package? 2) The `conhost.exe` is console host that is executed for any console application, e.g. even for `cmd.exe`. So this is unrelated to your problem. 3) Have you tried redirection `plink` output to a log and inspecting the log. Or attach it here, so we can take a look too.

Comment: 1) Yes I have, I have checked the regstery to confirm.

Comment: 2) I agree, however what intrigues me is that whenever plink.exe hangs(thats when I haven't RDPed into server) I see another console.exe process created in task manager, as soon as I end this process plink.exe is removed too, but when I have RDPed into server, this process gets created but finishes by itself, and so does plink.exe 3)Working on this one

Comment: 3) When running from daemons, the command succedes(again only when I am RDPed in, not otherwise) but does not log, however if I execute the same command from command prompt, it logs.

Comment: What did you do to make it log? `plink.exe` always outputs something (at least when it works, what you cleam to), so it's just matter of finding out, how to capture that output.

Comment: For logging. When I run the command by typing it on command prompt, it succeeds and prints the correct output. However, when I run it from a daemon SSIS process, it does not log.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What did you do to make it log? How do you capture the output?

Comment: I was doint something like plink user@SERVER -pw password blah blah > C:\putty_logs\putty.log

Comment: However, I have resolved the issue. I looked into the plink.exe process dumn and found out that it was still looking for user to accept the host key. So, to do that I could do "echo Y | plink...." But I am executing the command from C# where I have to provide the file plink.exe and add parameters to it. So, I did this. "cmd.exe echo Y | plink suer@SERVER -pw password ...". I guess the reason it still wants me to accept the host key(even after accepting it in the beginning) is because we are using a proxy to execute these .dtsx packages(daemon processes)